# Filter null values from a Map in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Is it possible to filter null values from a map?

```
const myMap = new Map<string, string|undefined>([
  ['id1', 'value1'],
  ['id2', null],
  ['id3', 'value3'],
  ['id4', null],
]);
```

I would like my map with id1 and id4 only because the other ids have null values.

Thanks

Comment: Call the `filter` method on the array before you pass it to the map

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605880/14708135

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert to array, filter and create a map again:

```js
const myMap = new Map([
  ['id1', 'value1'],
  ['id2', null],
  ['id3', 'value3'],
  ['id4', null],
]);
const res = new Map(Array.from(myMap).filter(val => val[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.filter()`:

```js
const myMapFiltered = new Map([...myMap].filter(([key, value]) => value));
```

Or if you want to filter in place:

```js
for (let k of myMap.keys()) {
  if (!myMap.get(k))
    myMap.delete(k);
}
```